# PHPMail sending email right away

Tags: php

While I'm just trying to pull up data from the db, as soon as the page shows up with the data it is already sending an email. How can I prevent it from sending the email right away. What I want to happen is I retrieved data from the db > shows it to a page > edit the page > update the db and send an email. This is the only point where I want an email to be sent out.

Here is my entire EDITED CODE as per suggestion,

```
$update = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $update_args);
$date = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $date_args);
$result = NULL;
$colcomments = NULL;

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.DBname.';host='.DBhost.';port=';
try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, DBuser, DBpswd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(!isset($_SESSION['update'])) {

        $_SESSION['update'] = true;

        //retrieve values from database
        if($date['from'] !== NULL && $date['to'] !== NULL){
        // get table data
        $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `changeid`,  
        FROM `tracker` WHERE `scheduled_start_date` BETWEEN :d1 AND :d2';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':d1', $date['from'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':d2', $date['to'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

    }else {

        unset($_SESSION['update']);

        //put your mail function here
    function two_dim_array_to_html_table($arr){
    $ret = "<table border='1' width='auto' cellpadding='1px' cellspacing='0px' align='center'>\n";
    $ret .= "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach($arr[0] as $key => $val){
        $ret .= "\t\t<th>".$colcomments[$key]."</th>\n";
        }
    $ret .= "\t</tr>\n";
    foreach($arr as $row){
        $ret .= "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach($row as $column){
            $ret .= "\t\t<td>".$column."</td>\n";
            }
        $ret .= "\t</tr>\n";
        }
    $ret .= "<table>\n";
    return $ret;
    }

    if($result) {
        $Body = "<html>\n"
            . "<head>\n"
            . "</head>\n"
            . "<body>\n"
            . two_dim_array_to_html_table($result, $colcomments)
            . "</body>\n"
            . "</html>\n";
    //Setting up Mail

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        if (EMAIL_USE_SMTP) {
            // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            //useful for debugging, shows full SMTP errors
            //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
            // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPAuth = EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH;
            // Enable encryption, usually SSL/TLS
            if (defined(EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION)) {
                $mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
            }
            // Specify host server
            $mail->Host = EMAIL_SMTP_HOST;
            $mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
            $mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
            $mail->Port = EMAIL_SMTP_PORT;
        } else {
            $mail->IsMail();
        }
        $mail->From = EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS;
        $mail->FromName = EMAIL_FROM_NAME;
        $mail->AddAddress('test.test@domain.COM');
        $mail->Subject = 'Daily Tasks - "'.date('d-m-Y').'"';
        $mail->WordWrap = 100;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $Body;
        $mail->Send();
        }


        //update database records
        if(isset($update['id']) && is_array($update['id']) && !empty($update['id'])){
        $sql = "UPDATE `tracker`
            SET `changeid` = :bv_changeid
            WHERE `id` = :bv_id ";
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
            $stmt->bindParam(':bv_changeid', $changeid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':bv_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $updateRowCount = 0;

            // update multiple rows - all of selected in form
            foreach($update['id'] as $key => $val){
                $changeid = $update['changeid'][$val];
                $id = $val;
                $stmt->execute();
                $updateRowCount += $stmt->rowCount();
                }
            if($updateRowCount > 0){
                $message['info'][] = "Updated ".$updateRowCount." row/s";
                }
            else {
                $message['warning'][] = "Tracker db not updated.";
                }
            }
        else {
            $message['error'][] = "Prepare error!!!";
            }
        }

    }


}else {

    //show the normal calender/form
    if(is_array($result)){
    echo '
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Assign</legend>
        <div>Changes will affect updated rows only.</div>
        <p></p>
        <table width=auto cellpadding=1px cellspacing=0px border=1 align=center id=assign>

            <thead>
            <tr>';      

    // column comment from DB as column header
    foreach($result[0] as $key => $val){
        echo '<th align=center>'.$colcomments[$key].'</th>';
        }
    echo '
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
    foreach($result as $row => $info){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($info as $key => $val){
    if($key=='id'){
    echo '<td title="'.$colcomments[$key].'">'.$val.'.<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'['.$info['id'].']" value="'.$val.'" id="rowid_'.$val.'" /></td>';
         }
    else {
    echo '<td title="'.$colcomments[$key].'"><input type="text" name="'.$key.'['.$info['id'].']" value="'.$val.'" /></td>';
         }
         }
    echo '</tr>'; 
         }
    echo '
            </tbody>
            </table>


    </fieldset>';

}
}
}
```

Here is the entire code for the `Submit` button,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ticket Assignment</title>
</head>
<body class="oneColFixCtrHdr">
<script>
</script>

<div id="mainContent">

<?php
foreach($message as $key => $val){
    // show error, warning and info messages
    if(!empty($val)){
        echo '<div style="margin:4px;background:'.$bgcol[$key].';border:2px solid grey;border-radius:8px;">';
        foreach($val as $item){
            echo '<div style="margin:8px;">'.$item.'</div>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
        }
    }
?>
    <div>
    <form action="assign_test1.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
        <legend>Select Date</legend>
        <div>Select Date from and Date to</div>
        <p></p>
        <input type="date" name="from" id="from" value="<?=$date['from']; ?>" />
        <input type="date" name="to" id="to" value="<?=$date['to']; ?>" />
        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want the email to only be sent once you edit the date and click submit?

Comment: That is what actually is happening now, and I dont want it to be sending an email while I'm still retrieving data from db using the date filter. What I want to happen is when I click submit the first time (retrieving data) it will just load the page with the retrieved data. Then I will edit that data and send submit again to update db and at the same time send an email.

Comment: So the first time you click, it should retrieve the data, the second time you edit, it updates the database with the new values, shows you the value and mail it?

Comment: Yes that is correct. That is what I want to happen.

Comment: Yeah alright, easy. Is it just 1 submit button which handles both ?

Comment: Yes, just one submit button.

Answer (score 0):

**The code you provided doesn't have everything so I will explain how it should work**

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(!isset($_SESSION['update'])) {

        $_SESSION['update'] = true;
        //retrieve values from database


    }else {

        unset($_SESSION['update']);
        //put your mail function here
        //update database records

    }


}else {

    //show the normal calender/form
}
```

I hope this helps you.

If you need anything else, please let me know. I am here to help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your suggestion, I've edited my code above but I'm still having the same issue. Still sending email just as when I retrieved the data.

Comment: You forgot to set the $_SESSION['update''] after the value is retrieved from the database. Also, you did not start the session.

before any php code Add: session_start(); 
and add: $_SESSION['update'] = true;

Comment: I have this added on top of my php code - `session_start();
if ($_SESSION['update'] = 'true');`. I dont think I understand this `You forgot to set the $_SESSION['update'']`, is it not on this part `// get table data`

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry. Editing it right now but I thought you would know. Anyways, you have an extra "}" at the end of your code. Delete one and remember that small mistakes can ruin the whole code!

Comment: Thank you for that, I followed everything (I guess) and its still not working. Here is what i have `<?php session_start(); CODE HERE ?>`

Comment: @testyummy Sorry I was busy doing something else, anyway, it is obvious that it doesn't work because you don't even have an input field with the name "submit" to recheck on it! Also, put your form method="post" Also, why can't I see session_start() in your code ?

Comment: I've posted my entire code now, and yeah I do have the `Submit` button with `name="submit"`

Comment: The reason I could not edit your codes is that you have multiple files included so I would get a lot of errors and the file won't run. I tried making a PHP form/mail script locally and it worked fine with me by the script method I posted on the answer. I hope you understand!

Comment: Sorry for that, it is for that reason why I actually dont want to post my entire code. Anyways I managed to trim down my code with the essential part. I patterned the edited code to what you suggested and now when I click on submit, nothing happens. The data is not loading anymore after i select dates. And thank you for looking at my codes, I'm just really new to PHP so my apologies for some confusion.